# Is there a long version of \phantom?

Tags: phantom

Is there a macro or environment that hides its content, replacing it by blank space like `\phantom`, that accepts content consisting of multiple paragraphs?

(I am aware that I could use `\color{white}` as a workaround. However, I would prefer to really not print the hidden text. White text can still be seen in a PDF viewer.)

Comment: What do you want it to do if page breaks occur?

Comment: Also hiding what comes after it, I suppose.

Comment: Exactly, also hiding what comes after it.

Comment: The `censor` package can handle longer content (with some restrictions).

Comment: Following on @marijn's comment: the `censor` package has a command, `\blackout`, which can extend over multiple paragraphs.

Comment: `censor`'s `\blackout` does look interesting. It can't handle math or other environments, though, can it?

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Maybe other solutions can be considered.